# Basic RSpec issue - method runs but tests fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Given all the hype over TDD, I decided it was time to dig in and add that to the list of things to study.  I'm running into an issue, and I'm 100% certain it's just a function of something being wrong with my tests in RSpec.  I'm still brand new to RSpec, so I'm having trouble figuring it out... my method works just fine, but the test for the method does not.

**Method Code** (I know I can refactor this A LOT. This is one of the first Ruby programs I wrote awhile back, which explains the ugliness)

```
def caesar_cipher(string,offset)
   string=string.to_s
   offset=offset.to_i

   cipher=[]
   string.each_byte do |i| 
       #capital letters
       if (i>64 && i<91)
           if (i+offset)>90
               cipher << (i+offset-26).chr
           else
               cipher << (i+offset).chr
           end
       elsif (i>96 && i<123)
            if (i+offset)>122
                cipher << (i+offset-26).chr
            else
                cipher << (i+offset).chr
            end
        else
            cipher << i.chr
       end
    end
  cipher=cipher.join('')
  puts "The encrypted string is: #{cipher}"
end
puts "Enter the string you'd like to encrypt"
string=gets.chomp
puts "Enter the offset you'd like to use"
offset=gets.chomp
caesar_cipher(string,offset)
```

**Test Code** (Just for one generic case, *all lower case input*)

```
require './caesarCipher.rb'

describe "caesar_cipher"  do
    it 'should handle all lower case input' do
        caesar_cipher("abcdefg", 3).should == "defghij"
    end     
end
```

**Method output:**

```
$ ruby caesarCipher.rb 
Enter the string you'd like to encrypt
abcdefg
Enter the offset you'd like to use
3
The encrypted string is: defghij
```

**Test Output:**

```
$ rspec spec/caesar_cipher_spec.rb 
Enter the string you'd like to encrypt
Enter the offset you'd like to use
The encrypted string is: require './caesarCipher.rb'
The encrypted string is: defghij
F

Failures:

  1) caesar_cipher should handle all lower case input
     Failure/Error: caesar_cipher("abcdefg", 3).should == "defghij"
       expected: "defghij"
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/caesar_cipher_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 0.00542 seconds (files took 0.14863 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/caesar_cipher_spec.rb:4 # caesar_cipher should handle all lower case input
```

Any help on why the tests are failing?  Judging by the output it looks like it's running it twice or something in the tests.

Comment: You'd need to capture stdout in order to test the method as it stands. It's doing too much to test easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `cipher` or `return cipher` after this line

```
  puts "The encrypted string is: #{cipher}"
```

And it should work

To explain the fix given, the last expression in a method is the return value. You've passed the value to STDOUT but not as the return value of the method, so RSpec was failing.

Comment: perfect. I didn't realize interpolation in the last line wouldn't actually count as a return value.  By adding in cipher at the end, it worked just like it should. Thanks!

Comment: @tomtom To explain the fix given, the last expression in a method is the return value. You've passed the value to STDOUT but not as the return value of the method, so RSpec was failing.

Comment: Welcome and I'll add @iain explanation to the answer as well